# Lumia 1520 crashes during factory reset

Tags: insider-preview, windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-1520

I joined the Windows 10 preview program a while back and today I received an update on my phone. After I installed the update, I was presented with Windows 10's new interface. I was so thrilled until I realised i couldn't turn the wi-fi on. Attempting to do so give me an error: Can't do this at the moment...try again or restart. Of course restarting didn't help at all. So I decided to factory reset the phone. I went to About -> Reset your phone.

The phone restarted and the turning gears came up. Then after about two minutes, it crashed giving me the sad face :-( screen, and it then turned itself off. Turning the phone back on takes me back to the same process and crash screen... it essentially gets caught in a loop.

I tried holding down the Volumne Down key and then plug in the charger, but instead of the exclamation mark that I expect to see, the phone goes to the screen with the word Nokia, then restarts. It keeps doing that in a loop as long as I am holding down on the volume button. If I release the button, it goes back to the turning gear screen but then crashes again with the sad face, which takes us back to the original issue...

How the hell should I proceed from here??

Edit: I installed the Windows Recovery Tool on my PC, but the software doesn't even detect the phone... so I am not completely out of ideas....

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: It seem the Nokia Software Updater for Retail is not working anymore due to necessary servers being shut down. Try the Windows Devices Recovery Tool again, it has gotten a few updates in the past weeks.**

I just had the exact same issue with my Lumia 830 but was able to finally fix it! As you mentioned both doing a hard reset and using the Windows Device Recovery Tool didn't work.

I had more luck using the [Nokia Software Updated for Retail (Version 4.3.2)](http://www.mediafire.com/download/5g4iqpbelwwpu6e/NokiaSoftwareUpdaterForRetail_4.3.2.exe). 
It works similar to the Device Recovery Tool - plug in your phone and maybe restart it once pressing power and volume down. The software should then be able to download the correct ROM and afterwards install it.

I had to try different USB Ports on my notebook until my phone was recognized by the software but it worked eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds crazy but put your phone in the fridge in a ziplock bag while its trying to update.

What's happening is that your phone is overheating and when it does, it restarts as a safety feature...then try's to hard reset again.  You just need to keep the phone from getting so hot it goes into loop. You can hold it in front of a AC if you like...but just keep the phone cool and the hard reset should continue.

Comment: have you actually tried this? o.O

Comment: Uh... seriously? My Icon's gotten almost too hot to hold, and never yet restarted on me.

Comment: I don't remember it ever getting hot... sorry but that just makes no sense. Thanks for the help anyway.. This is a really old question btw. That phone has long been replaced by another.

Answer (score 0):

> I installed the Windows Recovery Tool on my PC, but the software
>   doesn't even detect the phone... so I am not completely out of
>   ideas....

The [Windows Device Recovery tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq) can reinstall the software on your Lumia even if your phone is not detected.

---

You can download the tool from Microsoft [here](https://repairavoidance.blob.core.windows.net/packages/WindowsDeviceRecoveryToolInstaller.exe). If you cannot install the software normally using this tool normally follow these procedures.

**Note** : You need an active internet connection on your PC.

1. Download and install the Windows device recovery tool from [here](https://repairavoidance.blob.core.windows.net/packages/WindowsDeviceRecoveryToolInstaller.exe) and Launch it.
2. Remove all USB device.
3. Switch off your phone.
4. In the device recovery tool, select Lumia and select **My phone is not detected**.
5. Connect you phone via USB, **only after clicking on the *My phone is not detected* button and in switched off state.**
6. Now your phone should Switch ON. It will stay in the logo splash screen. It will not go to the spinning gears.
7. The tool will automatically find your device.
8. Click Install the software.
9. Click on Continue.
10. It is okay if your phone goes to spinning gear at this stage.
11. Now it will download about 1.6GB-2GB for WP8.1 and 2.7GB for Windows 10 Mobile of files from the internet. Don't worry if it gets broken in the middle just hit retry it will resume from where it left.
12. Then the new OS will be installed on the phone.

The above method help me recover my phone from the spinning gear loop after it fell and switched off during an upgrade process. Recovery tool was at first unable to detect my phone as it would restart before it was  detected.

Comment: Sorry to say. but I tried every option in the recovery tool including 'my phone is not detected'.

Comment: @deutschZuid Alright, try this. Run the Recovery tool, remove all USB devices, Click my phone is not detected. Only now connect your device. Your device will turn on but will remain in the logo splash screen. Click install software. It will not matter if the phone goes to spinning gears after you clicked that. I too faced the spinning wheel auto loop problem(my phone fell off the table during update and battery fell off separately) and got my phone repaired this way. I have also updated my answer to reflect my comments